# Calling manually wp-load.php in conjunction with qtranslate-x I get file not found

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, qtranslate-x

I have some custom php code outside of the wp-content of the wordpress, ie www.xyz.com/test

Calling the code below it works just fine, BUT if I enable the qtranslate-x that will add the language literal ie www.xyz.com/fr/test the result is "404 file not found."

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

What can I do the resolve the problem ?

Comment: You need to either exclude URLs that begin with `/test/` or route your custom URLs in WordPress itself.

Comment: Excluding directly from htaccess does not seem to work. Routing urls to Wordpress is unknown method to me!

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need plugins  when loading wordpress core?
This is the core to load a minimum configuration (without plugins and themes):

```
   define('SHORTINIT', true);
   require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

If you need theme support you can this trick:

```
  define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '');
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

  /* start theme */
  get_header();
  the_content();
  get_footer();
```

All code in you functions.php should be loaded fine

Comment: Plugins many not but I need the theme for optical consistency

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check it tomorrow and I will let you know